# Responsive table for mobile not going full width (css)

Tags: css

I am trying to make all my tables uniform on my site so I am using an identical class call for tables. Everything works when browsing on desktop, but unfortunately I cannot get my tables to span the entire width of the page and space columns accordingly when testing on mobile, and some tables even remove the headers for some reason inexplicable reason!

Here is my css code,

```
table {

  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th {
background-color: #545556;
    color: white;
  padding: .425em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .75em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;    
}

table td {
  padding: .425em;
  text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
img {max-width: 30%;}

    table {
    align-items: center;
        border: 0;
        display: inherit;
        font-size: 0.5em;
        width: 100%;
  }
img {max-width: 30%;}
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
        overflow: hidden;
  }

table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }

  table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
        display: inherit;
        width: 100%;
  }

  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: .4em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

HTML;

```
<table >
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <th> TEST</th>
            <th> TEST</th>
            <th> TEST</th>
            <th> TEST</th>
            <th> TEST</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
            <td> TEST</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
            <td>TEST </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS Fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/dn1e9saL/1/

Comment: Please provide a fiddle to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please provide the `html` part as well

Comment: @FranklinPious added the css fiddle and generic html. you'll see the header disappear as you shrink the screen too!

Answer (score 0):

The header is disappearing because you set `position: absolute;` on it, and the table isn't full width because you set `display: inherit;` on it.

Just remove those styles in your media query and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the disappearing header! 

Now why is it not staying full width on mobile???

Comment: Did you remove `display: inherit` from `table` and `table tr` as well?

Comment: yeah, and some tables are now stacking instead of staying 'squished`

Comment: I'm not seeing that happen using those [changes to the code you provided](http://jsfiddle.net/dn1e9saL/6/). You'll have to edit your jsfiddle to include everything needed to accurately reproduce your problem.

Comment: i think I can deduce that this is a woocommerce error... they like to all god stacked for some reason :( ... need to find a css file that is woocommerce specific to make their tables NOT squished.

Comment: I'm confused. First you say your tables are supposed to stay 'squished', now you're saying they're not.

Comment: What I am saying is some of the tables are coded differently for css and have specific classes so they are not being called unless specific CSS identifier is used... so many of my woocommerce based tables are going stacked instead of squished (I want squished).

Comment: If you want to override their styles, you can add `!important` to your styles like `width: 100% !important;`.